# angularjs directive variable reference

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I really don't no this angularjs variable working.

look at the my code -> http://jsfiddle.net/a9etkyz7/1/

$scope.ref and $scope.ref2 is not working!

`$scope.ref= $scope.a`

this is not reference?

this is copy?

please tell me answer

Comment: What do you want to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only objects can be passed as reference, since `$scope.a` is assigned a primitive value, then changes to the assigned values in `$scope.ref` and `$scope.ref2` does not reflect to the changes of `$scope.a`.

Tol solve this, you can change `$scope.a` into an object that holds a reference to the value you wish to change, and assign it to both `$scope.ref1` and `$scope.ref2`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8h4xogdc/1/)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

*Controller*

```
//....
$scope.a = {value: 12};
$scope.ref = $scope.a;
$scope.ref2 = {copyVale2: $scope.a};
```

*Directive*

```
//....
scope.a.value = newVal;
```

**HTML**

```
<test value="value" a="a">
    <div>ref a : {{ref.value}}</div>
    <div>ref2 a : {{ref2.copyVale2.value}}</div>
    <div>a : {{a.value}}</div>
</test>
```

Comment: umm, i have one more question. why only objects can be passed as reference? why not working not object?

Comment: [Read this as a reference](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm)